# Перенести базу данных с локального на сервер

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, сервер

Есть БД, созданная в MS SQL Server Manager Studio. Как скопировать её на сервер?

Comment: Экспорт-импорт?

Comment: Посмотрите документацию, а именно `dump` базы `MS SQL Server`

Comment: @Morlok из локальной директории на удаленный сервер.

Comment: Ну так и в чем проблема, не могу понять? 0_о

Comment: Сделай дамп. А потом уже на сервере который тебе нужен, импортируй этот дамп (в формате SQL) в СУБД этого сервера.

Comment: жму правой кнопкой на базе -> задачи -> а что дальше не знаю(

Comment: @Сергей смотрел [это](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwixmtye-MHTAhWGFCwKHQ_sD9QQFggsMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fru-ru%2Flibrary%2Fms187510.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFHiYKl62gXoXGgXET4JrQtFvad1Q)?

Comment: @EugenEray dump - это самый кривой и ненадежный способ переноса базы. кривее некуда :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Варианты переноса:

1. Через меню Tasks делаете Back Up, копируете полученный файл на сервер (или на доступный и от вас и от сервера сетевой диск). Подключаетесь к серверу, делаете на нем через то же меню Restore.
2. Делаете (через то же меню) для базы Export Data-tier Application. Подключаетесь к удаленному серверу, делаете на нем Import Data-tier Application. Для этого способа есть ограничения в поддерживаемых фичах базы, но он не требует пробрасывания файла на сервер, и может быть использован с Azure SQL.
3. Через то же меню запускаете Copy Database Wizard. Требует запущенного SQL Server Agent.

Comment: а как поступить если сервер линуксовый а база создана на SQL Server ?

Comment: @Сергей поставить на сервер [SQL Server for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup) и восстановить базу на нем

Comment: можете поделиться ссылками на инфу по теме ? у меня локальный SQL Server под винду. удаленный планируют на линуксе, поэтому я поставил mysql интерфейс workench и пытаюсь перенести с SQL на mysql.

Comment: MySQL и SQL Server - это разные субд. с разными возможностями и даже немного немного разным синтаксисом. Не получится перенести взять и перенести базу с SQL Server на MySQL. Или ставьте SQL Server под linux и переносите на него, или переносите структуру (можно попробовать через import/export data в SQL Server, но все автоматом перенести не получится)

Comment: Так SQL Server под линукс уже выпустили ? Я читал что майкрософт в прошлом году только анонсировали выход