# Asp.net проект без Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Нужно запустить проект asp.net на другом компьютере. Перенёс .mdf к .sln файлу. Как запустить проект без Management Studio?
Класс SqlConnection инециализирован как:

```
SqlConnection (@"Data Source =(LocalDb); Initial Catalog = DBTest; Integrated Security = True")
```

Comment: Не совсем дубликат - но вы можете подключиться через Management Studio к другому компьютеру, и перенести базу стандартными способами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658760/ Насчет использования local db для живого хостинга: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603435/

Answer (score 3):

Файл с расширением `.mdf` - файл СУБД SQL Server. Установите локальный SQL Server. Далее воспользуйтесь утилитой SQLCMD и присоедините вашу БД к серверу командами T-SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE DatabaseName 
    ON (FILENAME = 'FilePath\FileName.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'FilePath\LogFileName.ldf'),        
    FOR ATTACH 
GO
```

Comment: Да. Если на компьютере стоит бесплатный SQL Server Express, то к нему нет SSMS из коробки и обычно разворачивают скриптами из командной строки. Однако не стоит забывать, что можно на компьютер поставить SSMS из отдельного дистрибутива и будет вам графический интерфейс, либо подключиться с другого компьютера в локальной сети. Плюсанул, но КМК вопрос можно дополнить.